# How to create common class used by both client and server-side in Dart

Tags: dart

I'm attempting to write a class that will be used by both my client and my server-side code.  I created a folder called 'common' at the same level in the folder tree as 'web' and 'bin' and created a dart file with my object.  It doesn't find the 'imports' so apparently this is not the right approach.

How does one create classes that can be used in common by both the server side code in 'bin' and the client side in 'web'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to be able to import it from another package the files must be under the lib directory.

If you want to import from web it should be in lib or web (or any subdirectory of those)
If you want to import from bin it should be in lib or bin (or any subdirectory of those)
...